# Javascript - 'x' is not a function

Tags: javascript, function

In my javascript file I am calling function `B` inside function `A`. I get the following error

`B is  not a function`.

How can I resolve this error?

```
exports.createRecord = function A() {
  B();

};

exports.B = () =>{
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assigning a property to an object does not put that property's name into scope as a standalone identifier. For similar reasons, the following will fail too:

```
const obj = {
  fn() {
    console.log('hi');
  }
};
fn();
```

And `module.exports` is just an object with the same sort of behavior.

Either do

```
exports.createRecord = function A() {
  exports.B();
};
```

or

```
exports.createRecord = function A() {
  B();
};

const B = () => {
};
exports.B = B;
```